# Choosing shared Linux AMI machine image for AWS

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I know next to nothing about server management and just got started with Amazon Web Services.

I want to deploy a Linux server which runs Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin as well as email capabilities (account mgmt and webmail interface) and backup capabilities. I want to administer the server with a **nice web user interface** like cPanel, doing things like file management, email account management, access to phpMyAdmin.

Therefore I thought about deploying a shared Linux AMI, instead of building and configuring the server myself. I want to make my life easy, that is, deploying something pre-existing which is easy to manage (web user interface) since I haven't got time to learn all about server management right now.

I found [this list](https://aws.amazon.com/amis?platform=Red+Hat&selection=platform) of images. Which one of these would fit my requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use case for EC2.  As Amazons CTO Werner Vogels said a few months ago *"an EC2 instance is not a server, it's a building block."*  EC2 is used to provide computing resources to an application that spans multiple, loosely-coupled services.  It's not a drop in replacement for a standard VPS.

That's not to say that a lot of people aren't using EC2 instances as servers.  However, these are often the same people who bitterly complain about excessive downtime on AWS without realizing that it's mostly their own fault.  An application **must** be designed to be deployed in a cloud-based environment when it's built on an IaaS platform like AWS.  If your application is not aware of autoscaling groups and other high-availability features then traditional dedicated hosting will be cheaper, less complex, and more durable than AWS.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all that. Do you also have the answer to the question?

Comment: If the question you're referring to is *"Which one of these would fit my requirements?"*, then my answer is "None of them, and for the reasons I outlined above."

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of AMI's for webmin, but not for cPanel.  Here is the link:

https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/aws/virtualmin_gpl_ami

I would echo the comments made by @jamieb however in that this is really not a good use case for EC2.  You are limited to a single elastic IP per instance, so you have no ability to do IP-based virtual hosts as you would with a typical VPS.